# Variable is undefined whereas it defined

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code below gives an undefined error on console for the variable `mystyle`. I don't get it as i defined the variable.

```
jQuery( '.styles_div' ).each( function() {
switch (styles) {
    case 'style1':
        var mystyle = $('#stylewrap').append('<div class="style1"></div> ');
        break;
    case 'style2':
        var mystyle = $('#stylewrap').append('<div class="style2"></div> ');
        break;
}
$("#search").autocomplete({
    delay: 0,
    minLength: 3,
    search: function( event, ui ) {mystyle.show();},
    ...
})
});
```

Comment: it will be undefined if styles is neither style1 nor style2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mystyle needs to be defined before it is used - perhaps as a global var and not have the var keyword twice. It is also prudent to test the existence

```
var mystyle;
switch (styles) {
    case 'style1':
        mystyle = $('#stylewrap').append('<div class="style1"></div> ');
        break;
    case 'style2':
        mystyle = $('#stylewrap').append('<div class="style2"></div> ');
        break;
}
$("#search").autocomplete({
    delay: 0,
    minLength: 3,
    search: function( event, ui ) {if (mystyle) mystyle.show();},
    ...
})
```

if this is the complete code, then perhaps this code is simpler:

```
var mystyle = $('#stylewrap').append('<div class="'+styles+'"></div> ');
```

Answer (score 1):

Define `mystyle` before `switch case`. otherwise the code is correct.